# UIButtonTypeInfoLight inside rounded rect?

Tags: iphone, button, ios, uibarbuttonitem

I know, I know, it's a venial aesthetic question, but I want to insert an info button in my navigation bar not as the default info UIButton (UIButtonTypeInfoLight), but inside a rounded rect so that it appears in a uniform manner to the other UIBarButtonItem buttons.
Is it possible that there is no way?
Using custom UIButton with an image (of "i" inside a circle) is the only way? Do you know what the font is for this italic "i"?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end I made a custom UIButton with an image:
http://cl.ly/1u2X3Z082A1l25341u2B 
http://cl.ly/163U0x0N0n222x132e3q (2x)

Font used: Adobe Garamond Pro

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for sure, but the font for the info "i" looks like Arno Pro, italic. Probably bold:

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/arno/bold-italic-caption/